# SQL to work out sales by product taking into account age

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to work out sales by product grouped by release date, but also grouped by the age of that product when sold, something like this:

```
        | 3 months | 6 months    
2015-01 | 28.1     | 37.1
2015-02 | 29.3     | 35.6
```

So 28.1 is the average number of products sold of each type, 3 months after being released, for those products released in 2015-01. There are obviously more products sold 6 months after the release date, 37.1.

The following SQL gets a list of sales:

```
SELECT
  d.item               AS title,
  d.quantity,
  a.firstdate          AS release_date,
  i.date               AS invoice_date,
  i.date - a.firstdate AS age

FROM invoices i
  JOIN invoice_details d ON i.id = d.invoice_id

  JOIN (SELECT
          d.item,
          d.binding,
          min(i.date) AS firstdate
        FROM invoices i
          JOIN invoice_details d ON i.id = d.invoice_id
        GROUP BY d.item, d.binding) AS a ON a.item = d.item AND a.binding = d.binding

WHERE
  i.discount != 100 AND d.price > 0
  AND (d.binding != 'Hardback' OR d.binding != 'Ebooks')

ORDER BY title, invoice_date
```

And the result looks something like:

```
title | quantity | release date | invoice date | age
A     | 1        | 2013-11-14   | 2013-11-14   | 0
A     | 2        | 2013-11-14   | 2013-12-14   | 30
A     | 3        | 2013-11-14   | 2014-01-14   | 60
A     | 4        | 2013-11-14   | 2014-02-14   | 90
A     | 5        | 2013-11-14   | 2014-03-14   | 120
B     | 6        | 2013-11-14   | 2013-11-14   | 0
B     | 7        | 2013-11-14   | 2013-12-14   | 30
B     | 8        | 2013-11-14   | 2014-01-14   | 60
B     | 9        | 2013-11-14   | 2014-02-14   | 90
B     | 10       | 2013-11-14   | 2014-03-14   | 120
```

For product A, the total sales 3 months after the release date of 2013-11-14 are 1+2+3=6. For product B, total sales 3 months after are 6+7+8=21.
Average sales per title for the month of 2013-11, 3 months after are (6+21)/2=13.5

For 6 months after it's ((1+2+3+4+5) + (6+7+8+9+10)) / 2 = 27.5

The release date is just the first date the product was sold - this is what the joined sub-query is for. There is probably a better way of doing it.

I tried this to get the averages across 3, 6, 12 and 24 months:

```
SELECT
  to_char(a.release_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS release_date,

  avg(CASE WHEN i.date - a.release_date < 92
    THEN d.quantity END)             AS three_months,

  avg(CASE WHEN i.date - a.release_date < 183
    THEN d.quantity END)             AS six_months,

  avg(CASE WHEN i.date - a.release_date < 365
    THEN d.quantity END)             AS twelve_months,

  avg(CASE WHEN i.date - a.release_date < 730
    THEN d.quantity END)             AS twentyfour_months

FROM invoices i
  JOIN invoice_details d ON i.id = d.invoice_id

  JOIN (SELECT
          d.item,
          d.binding,
          min(i.date) AS release_date
        FROM invoices i
          JOIN invoice_details d ON i.id = d.invoice_id
        GROUP BY d.item, d.binding) AS a ON a.item = d.item AND a.binding = d.binding

WHERE
  i.discount != 100 AND d.price != 0
  AND (d.binding != 'Hardback' OR d.binding != 'Ebooks')


GROUP BY release_date
ORDER BY release_date desc
```

Obviously it's totally wrong because it's not grouping the results by title. It's giving me the average items per order rather than the average items per title.

By the way I am stuck on Postgres 8.2.

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data.

Comment: I added sample data for the first query, which sample data do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you want:

```
SELECT
  to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') AS release_date,
  avg(CASE WHEN age <  92 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS three_months,
  avg(CASE WHEN age < 183 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS six_months,
  avg(CASE WHEN age < 365 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS twelve_months,
  avg(CASE WHEN age < 730 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS twentyfour_months
FROM (
  SELECT d.item, d.quantity, (i.date - first_release.date) AS age, fr.date
  FROM invoice_details d
  JOIN (
    SELECT d.item, min(i.date) AS date
    FROM invoice_details d
    JOIN invoices i ON i.id = d.invoice_id
    WHERE d.binding != 'Hardback' AND d.binding != 'Ebooks'
    GROUP BY d.item) AS fr USING (item)
  JOIN invoice i ON i.id = d.invoice_id
  WHERE i.discount != 100 AND d.price > 0) AS foo
GROUP BY release_date
ORDER BY release_date;
```

This is quite obviously untested because I can't even remember when I last touched an 8.2 installation. Your version does not have common table expressions or lateral joins, to name two critical features in later releases that would have made this rather more intuitive.

Anyway, the trick is to first calculate the age of every invoice relative to the book release date for every book sold, then average it out over the various time periods. Look carefully at the filters as I moved them and slightly altered them (`(d.binding != 'Hardback' OR d.binding != 'Ebooks')` is very likely not what you want).

Comment: It runs with a few minor corrections but doesn't produce the right results. It's producing numbers mostly in the range 0-1 whereas I know they are more like 30-70.
It still seems to be treating titles separately, so that the averages are items per order rather than items per title.